# What playing techniques are sensitive to "jamming fingers"

Tags: technique, keyboard, digital-piano, health

A [Korg Krome 61/73 review](http://www.kromecity.com/korg-krome-61-review) mentions that you can jam fingers between two keys because they are flat. I've had an opportunity to play some cheap keyboards with flat keys and this didn't happen to me.

For considering this issue while buying a new synth, I would like to know: which playing techniques are vulnerable to this happening? And is it truly a problem at all (i.e., can it really happen when you play the keyboard or is it just another negative remark in the overall negative review)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably most likely to occur if you are stretching your hand, playing notes for apart, then a part of your finger could get stuck under a key, which wouldn't be good fun while playing a piece.

However, if you have good piano technique and keep your hands over the keyboard, rather than beyond the end of it, this shouldn't really happen.